# Easy way to construct a timeline in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, audio

I am using the `AudioContext()` object to create a slight soundtrack for a canvas game I am making. In order to do this, however, I need to play certain events at a certain point in time. I currently have:

```
function playRingTone(){
    var osc = ctx.createOscillator();
    osc.connect(ctx.destination);
    osc.start(0);
    osc.frequency.value = 200;
    setTimeout(function(o){
        console.log(true);
        o.frequency.value = 300; 
        setTimeout(function(o){
            console.log(true);
            o.frequency.value = 350; 
            setTimeout(function(o){
                console.log(true);
                o.frequency.value = 375; 
                setTimeout(function(o){
                    console.log(true);
                    o.frequency.value = 400; 
                    setTimeout(function(o){
                        console.log(true);
                        o.frequency.value = 380; 
                        setTimeout(function(o){
                            console.log(true);
                            o.frequency.value = 360; 
                            setTimeout(function(o){
                                console.log(true);
                                o.frequency.value = 375; 
                            },600,o);
                        },200,o);
                    },200,o);
                },200,o);
            },200,o);
        },1500,o);
    },1000,osc);
}
```

This, however, is ***highly*** cumbersome, and is hard to edit and create. Is there a better way to do it? I am willing to use libraries, but a pure JS way is preferred. Thanks!

Comment: Those timeouts aren't all that accurate anyway.  It would be far better to use the functionality built into the Web Audio API.  Check this out:  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/

Comment: @Brad Does it work with Firefox?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio-api